# How to fix the error expected 0 but got 1 arguments for fileReader method using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i am trying to create a use hook which accepts a file, reads its content and returns string using FileReader.

in doing so, i get error "expected 0 but got 1 arguments" for FileReader. below is the code,

```
const noop = () => {}
const useFileReader = (options: any) ) => {
    const {file, method="readAsText", onload: onloadHook = noop} = options;
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [result, setResult] = useState<string | ArrayBuffer | null>(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!file) return;
        const reader = new FileReader(file); //error here
    
        reader.onloadstart = () => {
            setLoading(true);
        }

        reader.onloadend = () => {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    
        render.onload = (e: any) => {
            setResult(e?.target?.result);
            onloadHook(e?.target?.result);
        }
   
        render.onerror = (e: any) => {
            setError(e);
        }

        try {
            reader[method](file)
        } catch(e) {
            setError(e); 
        }
    }, [file])
    
    return [{ result, error, file, loading }]
}


const Parent = () => {

   const { result, error, loading } = useFileReader(file);

   return (
       //some jsx
   );
```

}

Could someone help me fix the error. thanks.

Comment: FileReader is a class first you declare like 

const reader = new FileReader();

then use reader to read file like 

reader.readAsText(file)

or use other method.

Comment: thanks. like in my case in try block how can i rewrite it? reader.[method](file) doesnt seem to be right

Comment: when i use it like reader[method](file) i get error "element has explicitly has any type because expression of type 'any' cant be used to index type 'FileReader'

Comment: var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (e) {
//do whatever you want to
}
reader.readAsDataURL(file);